# Can I set an angular-ui alert timeout to a variable?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create an angular-ui-bootstrap alert where the timeout is set programmatically. I read about the dismiss-on-timeout property in the [angular-ui docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert).

This seems to work:

```
<uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" dismiss-on-timeout=5000 type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>
```

However, can I do the following, using a variable? It doesn't seem to work :(

```
<uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" dismiss-on-timeout="{{alert.timeout}}" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)" >{{alert.msg}}</uib-alert>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'danger', timeout: 5000, msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
    { type: 'success', timeout: 5000, msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Comment: Looking at what you wrote there seems nothing wrong with it. Can you post the controller and the definition of `alert`?

Comment: @RicardoVelhote Did so :) It is the controller from the docs, with a timeout added to the alerts.

Comment: Well, I think it is too early to call "alert.type" as you're on the same line as the ng-repeat. Maybe create a global variable or a second Controller to your "body" tag and create a timeout there first.

Comment: I've looked into the ui.alert.js file and it seems that they are not evaluating the expression means it is injected as string therefore your dismissOnTimeout I would say looks like an Issue of the lib

Comment: seems to be working now. using angular 1.4.7 and angular-bootstrap 0.14.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go:

- It really looks like angular-ui Alert doesn't offer the possibility of using it. I've debugged it and made changes myself, if you're interested in:

ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.2.js:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.alert', [])

.controller('UibAlertController', ['$scope', '$attrs', '$timeout', function($scope, $attrs, $timeout) {
  $scope.closeable = !!$attrs.close;
 debugger;

  if (angular.isDefined($scope.dismissOnTimeout)) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.close();
    }, parseInt($scope.dismissOnTimeout, 10));
  }
}])

.directive('uibAlert', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'UibAlertController',
    controllerAs: 'alert',
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
      return attrs.templateUrl || 'template/alert/alert.html';
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      type: '@',
      close: '&',
      dismissOnTimeout: '=',
    },
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      debugger;
      console.log("link");

    }
  };
});
```

In your "app.js" add to your "AlertController":

```
  $scope.timeout = 1000;
```

And in your HTML file:

```
  <uib-alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" dismiss-on-timeout="timeout" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}, {{alert.timeout}}</uib-alert>
```

I've forked the demo plunkr from angularjs and added my own angular-ui-bootstrap code... [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xZEJD1aB9mcjXvBNqt91?p=preview)

Comment: Nice tip. But you have a small problem with your code: if user will dynamically change value of timeout - it will not work. See this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/YkUpFveriXntm342Qk17?p=preview . Here user can dynamically change values of timeout + `dismissOnTimeout` is binded via `'@'` parameter.

Comment: @ababashka you're right, will update my code soon to reflect you're solution;)

Comment: Thank you to you both @ferto and @ababashka! I got it working, much appreciated :)

Comment: @FerTo, i make same code as per your code but alert is displaying perfectly but it's not hide on dismiss timeout bases.

Comment: Sorry for that but I've to admit it is already 1+ year old and I don't use angular1 or uib-alert anymore.